# What is the difference between 毎回 and 毎度?

Tags: word-choice, nuances

Both 毎{まい}回{かい} and 毎{まい}度{ど} share the meaning of "every time" or "every occurrence."

I know 毎回 can be used to mean "every turn", and that 毎度 can be used to mean "frequently" too.

Does that mean 毎回 is more often related to attempting things several times, whereas 毎度 is more closely linked to just things that happen often?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but 毎度 is often used by stores/restaurants as a "thank you" to the customers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [this thesaurus entry](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/thsrs/15061/meaning/m1u/%E6%AF%8E%E5%9B%9E/) says, 'each time'-ness is felt less with 毎度. As such it is close to 'always' and more often used in fixed phrases.

- 毎度ありがとうございます Thank you for always (shopping with us).
- 毎度のことだけれども Though this happens always, ...
- 毎度毎度いい加減にしてほしい I'm fed up with this happening all the time.

In all of the above, 毎回 is less idiomatic (for the last one, 毎回毎回 can be used).